# What could I grep for in strace output from a gevent app to test whether it's using blocking network IO?

Tags: python, asynchronous, gevent, strace

I have a small gevent server that also is an http client of other apis.  One library I use has httplib as a dependency.

I do monkey.patch_all.  There's no disk IO, just network.

I'm rusty on my system calls, but I was wondering if there'd be a simple way to test for whether blocking calls are being made using strace.

I know how to use strace but am not sure exactly what I might grep for.

Would this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went ahead an experimented a bit myself and think I found at least a partial answer.

I made a throwaway webapp that simply sleeps 5 seconds then responds 'hello'.

Then I wrote two clients.  One uses python requests, the other uses grequests (an asynchronous requests module).

First client:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://localhost:1234')
```

Second client:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import grequests

req = grequests.get('http://localhost:1234')
resp = grequests.map([req])[0]
```

I ran these as:

```
strace -T -f -s1000  python blocking_io.py &> out
```

In the output of the (expected) blocking version, I get:

```
sendto(3, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:1234\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1\r\n\r\n", 144, 0, NULL, 0) = 144 <0.000022>
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR) <0.000008>
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)               = 0 <0.000007>
recvfrom(3, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 77 <5.009440>
recvfrom(3, "Server: Werkzeug/0.11.5 Python/2.7.10\r\nDate: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 22:28:38 GMT\r\n\r\nHello World!", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 90 <0.000067>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000175>
```

Note the 5 second wait time at the end of the line for the first `recvfrom`.

Then I did it for the async version:

```
[pid 24359] sendto(5, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:1234\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1\r\n\r\n", 144, 0, NULL, 0) = 144 <0.000023>
[pid 24359] fcntl(5, F_GETFL)           = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) <0.000008>
[pid 24359] fcntl(5, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0 <0.000008>
[pid 24359] recvfrom(5, 0x2481624, 8192, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <0.000009>
[pid 24359] epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 5, {EPOLLIN, {u32=5, u64=8589934597}}) = 0 <0.000008>
[pid 24359] epoll_wait(3, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=5, u64=8589934597}}}, 64, 59743) = 1 <5.009130>
[pid 24359] recvfrom(5, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\nServer: Werkzeug/0.11.5 Python/2.7.10\r\nDate: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 22:29:50 GMT\r\n\r\nHello World!", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 167 <0.000114>
[pid 24359] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000185>
```

In this case the 5 seconds is spend doing `epoll_wait`.

Additionally, where the blocking version does

```
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)
```

The asynch version does

```
fcntl(5, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
```